# pydev and twisted framework

Tags: python, eclipse, twisted, pydev

It seems like my Eclipse PyDev does not recognize that Twisted is installed on my system. I can't make auto suggest working. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

go to preferences->Pydev->Interpreter - Python and hit the apply button. That will rescan your modules directory and add any missing modules.

That should fix any normal import errors. Some modules do some runtime magic that PyDev cant follow.

Comment: Two such modules in Twisted are `twisted.internet.reactor` and `twisted.application.internet` (which you can work around by adding them to "forced builtins").  However, everything else should auto-complete just fine without any special effort.

Comment: I added "twisted" to the Forced Builtins and everything works OK (i.e. no import/undefined errors and completion working correctly)